# Upgrading kernel in live ISO file?

Tags: linux-kernel, upgrade

I'm no Linux expert and I need to upgrade the kernel, and some applications, in a Ubuntu live ISO file whose structure looks like this:

[image]

I've never done this before, and would like to check something before going further:

To update the kernel, I was thinking of downloading and unpacking the latest kernel package, eg. linux-image-2.6.31-22-386_2.6.31-22.63_i386.deb.

The data.tar.bz2 in the package contains ./boot (System.map, abi, config, vmcoreinfo, vmlinuz), ./lib (firmware/, modules/), and ./usr (share/doc).

I suspect upgrading the kernel is a bit more involved than just replacing vmlinuz in the ISO file in /casper: What about references in configuration files? Do I also need to replace /lib with those in the package? Is building a new initrd.gz required too?

Then, after chrooting into the squashfs (ie. the root filesystem that will be unpacked in RAM), "apt-get upgrade" will download newer versions of the applications, so what about MD5 hashfiles, manifests, etc.?

Thank you for any help.